# How to create an Instance Store-Backed AMI by python boto script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ami

I use the following code in python/boto to create an AMI

```
dev_sda1 = BlockDeviceType()
dev_sda1.size = 30 # change root volume to 30GB instead of default
bdm = BlockDeviceMapping()
bdm['/dev/sda1'] = dev_sda1

ami_id = ec2_connection.create_image(instance.id, name="NewAmi,  description="NewAMI",
                           block_device_mapping=bdm)
```

This code creates the AMI with the ebs Root Device Type

Is it possible to create an Instance Store-Backed AMI?

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to always use Amazon EBS root volumes. What is your particular need for using an Instance Store-backed AMIs?

Comment: We have too many EBS volumes than need to be deleted

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Are you saying that the account has hit a limit on the number of EBS volumes? By default, when an instance is terminated, the root volume is also deleted, so it should self-cleanup. It looks like creating an instance store-baked AMI requires quite a few operations on the instance itself, rather than simply being an API call. See: [Creating an AMI from an Instance Store-Backed Instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-instance-store-ami.html#amazon_linux_instructions)

Comment: Yes, for EBS volumes we need to pay, and they stay after an is terminated

Comment: Which limit are you hitting? There is a limit of 300 TiB of each type of disk storage, but you can ask for a limit increase. Or is this purely a desire to reduce your storage costs? I would advise against using Instance Store-backed AMIs because you cannot Stop and Start such instances (you can only terminate them) and you would lose the content of the root volume.

Comment: Yes, there is a need to reduce a storage cost

Comment: You could also consider [changing the volume type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html), or archiving unwanted volumes as Snapshots. A standard Amazon Linux instance wants an 8GB volume and Windows wants 30GB. A 30GB General Purpose disk would cost $3/month ($36/year). That isn't much of a cost saving you'll achieve compared to the cost of your time to implement the change.

Comment: Changing the volume type - is it at AMI creation?

Comment: The Instance Type is selected when launching an instance: General Purpose SSD, Provisioned IOPS (guaranteed speed, but more costly) or Magnetic (slower, can be cheaper depending upon usage pattern). So, if you want to reduce costs, first check that you are not using Provisioned IOPS.

Comment: "guaranteed speed" of what?

Comment: See: [Amazon EBS Volume Types - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html)